# TypeError: 0 is not a string

Tags: python, string, statistics, scatter-plot

I received this error when trying to compile my code. I extracted data from xlsx file and created a dataframe ,replaced null values with 0 and selected two columns to scatter plot but received this error

```
raise TypeError("{val!r} is not a string".format(val=val))
TypeError: 0 is not a string
```

and this is the code I did so far

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xlsxfile = pd.ExcelFile  
("C:\\Users\\Aymen\\Desktop\\PL44_ABH_14_09_2018_SC_Level.xlsx")
data = xlsxfile.parse('Sheet1', index_col = None, header = None)
data1 = data.fillna(0)
X = data1.iloc[0:len(data1),1] 
print(X)
Y = data1.iloc[0:len(data1),2] 
print(Y)
axes = plt.axes()
axes.grid() 
plt.scatter(X,Y) 
plt.show()
```

To notice that I am a beginner with this.

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: What's the output of `data1.info()`?

Answer (score 1):

I had just simply to convert my dataframe to String values using this command:

```
data1 = data1.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do `data1 = data.fillna('0')` to force the substitution value (0) to be a string.